# SQL Data in form of Date+Time bulk insert into one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, import

**Background of problem:** To insert 2 seperated fields of data (from a big flat file document of data) with bulk insert. Columns in question that i want to get data from is in its current form in date time format (in flat file document).

**I want to:** insert these 2 fields of data into one column.

**Idea of solution:** Is it possible by xml format file point the fields of data into one column?

Example code (One line of data):

```
2016-01-01  00:00:00            GTM         clocktic
```

Into column:

```
   [TStamp] [datetime]     NOT NULL,
```

With Format file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="20"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="#" COLLATION="Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="#" COLLATION="Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="#" COLLATION="Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="#" COLLATION="Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="#" COLLATION="Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LEN GTH="#" COLLATION="Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="#" COLLATION="Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="#" COLLATION="Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="11" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="#" COLLATION="Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="12" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="#" COLLATION="Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="13" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="#" COLLATION="Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="14" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\n" MAX_LENGTH="#" COLLATION="Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="TStamp" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="var2" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="var3" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="var4" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="var5" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="var6" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="var7" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="var8" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="var9" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="var10" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="11" NAME="var11" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="12" NAME="var12" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="13" NAME="var13" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Comment: Can you not load them separately then concatenate them into a third field post-load?

Comment: That would just sugarcoat my problem from my perspective, I am really interested if i cant define them as 2 fields in the format file and point them into one column. I am just not sure of the process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can process the data using regular T-SQL as part of the bulk loading process, using the [`OPENROWSET(BULK...`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms175915.aspx) function and the XML format file.

```
INSERT <target> WITH (TABLOCKX)
    <target_column_list>
SELECT
    <columns_and_expressions>
FROM OPENROWSET
(
    BULK <data_file>,
    FORMATFILE = <xml_format_file>,
    ... <other_options>
) AS alias;
```

The key part is the `<columns_and_expressions>` in the select clause. This provides a lot of flexibility.

A more concrete example:

```
INSERT dbo.zz_u_test_TEMP WITH (TABLOCKX)
(
    col1_dirty, col2_dirty, col3_dirty, col4_dirty, col5_dirty,
    col6_dirty, col7_dirty, col8_dirty, col9_dirty, col10_dirty
)
SELECT
    REPLACE(RowSource.col1_dirty, CHAR(34), SPACE(0)),
    REPLACE(RowSource.col2_dirty, CHAR(34), SPACE(0)),
    REPLACE(RowSource.col3_dirty, CHAR(34), SPACE(0)),
    REPLACE(RowSource.col4_dirty, CHAR(34), SPACE(0)),
    REPLACE(RowSource.col5_dirty, CHAR(34), SPACE(0)),
    REPLACE(RowSource.col6_dirty, CHAR(34), SPACE(0)),
    RowSource.col7_dirty,
    RowSource.col8_dirty,
    RowSource.col9_dirty,
    RowSource.col10_dirty
FROM OPENROWSET
(
    BULK 'C:\Documents and Settings\Paul\Test.data', 
    FORMATFILE = 'C:\Documents and Settings\Paul\format.xml',
    CODEPAGE = 'RAW',
    FIRSTROW = 0,
    LASTROW = 0,
    MAXERRORS = 0,
    ROWS_PER_BATCH = 0
) AS RowSource;
```

This gives you the potential benefits of minimally-logged fast bulk load, while applying transformations in the `SELECT` clause.

That is a code example [I wrote years ago](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost916633.aspx) for a different problem, but it should work for you. If I get a moment to create a table and file (not supplied in the question), I might add a more specific version.